# Generate SVG Path based on existing shapes

Tags: svg

I have a map generated based on many svg paths hard coded in my application. There are 2 paths specifically, shown in the picture below that I need to update.

Path 1 specifies the outline of the shape and path 2 divides the shape in 2 parts.

I need to change this to have 2 new paths, to have 2 shapes each for each side of the divider. Is there any way to generate this based on the existing paths?

```css
.region{fill:#B4B4B4;}
.divider{ fill:none; stroke-width:.04em; stroke:#000000; }
```

```html
<svg width="635" height="500">
<g transform="scale(1.0400000000000003) translate(-114.01880110476836, -686.9230769230768)">
 <path d="M580.9,1036.4c-1,0-2.1,0.2-3.1,0c-1.2-0.2-2.5-0.4-3.6-0.9c-1.3-0.6-2.9-1.7-4.4-1.8 c-0.7-0.3-5.7-0.4-6.9-0.1c-1.8,0.1-4,1.5-5,2.9c0,0-6.3-5.8-6.9-10.4c0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.1-1.4c-0.1-1.2-0.2-2.5-0.7-3.7 c-0.3-0.7-0.8-1.3-1.2-1.9c-0.6-0.9-1.3-1.8-1.5-2.9c-0.1-0.5-0.1-1,0-1.5c0.1-1.3,0.8-2.6,1.5-3.9c0.8-1.4,1.5-2.8,1.6-4.2 c0-1.5-0.7-3-1.3-4.3c-1.4-3-2.9-6.2-5.3-8.7c-0.8-0.8-1.7-1.6-2.5-2.3c-1.1-1-2.3-2-3.2-3.2c-1.5-1.9-2.7-4.9-1.2-7.3 c0,0,0.8-1.2,1-1.5c0.4-0.8,0.6-1.6,0-2.1c-0.2,0-1.9-0.9-2.3-1.8l-0.5,1.2l-1.9,0.9l-2.6,0.2l-2.7-0.6l-1.5,1.4l-2.6-0.8l-1.6,0.2 l-1.4-2.7l-3.2-1.1l-7.1,4l0.1,0.8l-0.2,2.7l-5.8,2.6l-1.5-0.5l-4.9-4l-2-0.3l-4.2,0.9l-3.3-2.2l-3.6-0.3l-7.9,3.6l-0.6,2.8 l-1.3,1.5l0.5,3.4l-3.3,2.9l0.3,3.7l3.9,1.1l2.3,0.2l2.5,1.9l4.2,0.9l3.4,3l-1.6,2.7l-3.5,1.3l-1,1.9l-0.5,4.7l-2.4,1.6l-1.2,3.9 l-3.7,2.6l0.1,0.9l1.7,4.5l1.8-0.2l1.3-1.6l5.1-3l1.2,0.2l1.4,2l0.4,2l-4.1,4.7l-7.6,0.7l-6.6,2.8l-3,2.2l0.3,2.1l2.3,1.4l7.4,5.5 l3.6,2.1l9.6,0.9l-0.1,2l-2.6,2l-0.8,1.4l0.3,1.2l2.8,1.3l0.4,1.5l-0.8,0.7l-3.4,0.8l-4,2.2l-1.7,2.5l-2.6,4.6l-0.3,1l1.1,0.5 l1.1,0.6l-1.1,2l-2.3,1.2l-0.2,0.7l1.3,1.4l-1.1,1.3l-0.2,3.1l2.8,2.2l1,3.5l4.4,6.1l2.7,2.1l1.3,2.6l1.8,1.3l1.4,0.3l4-2l2.2-0.3 l8.4,6.3l3.2,3.8l3.1,0.3l3.6,2.3l0.7-0.3l0.5-2.7l0.9-1.1l0.9,0.2l0.6,1.4l1.5-0.8l1.1,0.1l0.7-1.1l2.4-0.8l2.6,0.3l1.4-2.4l3-0.3 l2.9-1.5l-1-1.2l-1.3-3.4l-1.3-1.2l-0.6-1.1l0.2-2l0.9-1.4l-0.3-1.3l1.5-2.8l1.7,0.7l1.2,2.2l1.1,0.5l1.5-0.5l2.3-2.1l2.4-0.3 l3.3,4.8l4.6,1.2l1.3-0.1l2.2-2.9l2.4,1l0.9-0.8l-0.4-1.9l0.1-3.8l1-0.3l4.2-0.3l-2.2,4.7l1.7,1l1.5-1.6h3.1l3.4,0.9l5-2.9l2.6-0.5 l5.3,0.6l3.5,2.3l0.7-1.7l-1.8-2.2l-1.6-0.9l0.1-1.5l1.9-1.5l2.6,0.4l2.7-3.5l1.9-0.9l2.2,1.9l2,0.7l0.8,2.2l2.7,3.8l1.3,0.4l3-0.4 l1,0.5l0.6,0.9l-4.2,4.1l4.6,3.2l0.9-1.3l2.8-0.2l0.6-1.8l2.1-0.4l1.7-5.7v-2.3l2.5-3.6l2.5-0.3v-1.5l1.4-0.6l1.9,0.2l2.3,1.7 l1.5-0.3l0.4-0.6l-1.6-1.4v-0.6l2.6-1.8l0.6-2.1l2.7-3.4l4.7-1.7l0.2-0.8l-1.7-1.8l0.2-1.2l4.8-2.5l-0.1-2.2l-1.2-1.6l1.7-1.9 l-2.9-0.7l-0.8-1.7l6-2.2l1.2-0.8l-3.9-7.4l-2.6-1.3l-4.5-6.1l-8.8-3.8l-1.9-2.7l-6.7-2.4l-2.1-2.1l-2.3-0.7v-2.6v-0.1 c-1,1.3-1.7,4.7-1,6.1c0.6,0.9,1.3,1.7,2.1,2.5c0.4,0.4,0.8,0.9,1.2,1.3c1.9,2.2,2.9,5,3,8.2c0,0.5,0,1.1-0.4,1.5 c-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.4c-2.2,1.2-4.8,2.4-7.5,2.4c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0c-1.1,0-2.3-0.5-3.3-0.7c-2.8-0.5-5.5-1.2-8.2-1.9 c-3.8-1-7.7-2.1-11.7-2.5C584.7,1036.5,581.2,1036.4,580.9,1036.4z" fill="white" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="region" cursor="pointer"></path> 
 <path d="M589.4,1078.4c-5.3-2.6-8.9-6.8-12.1-10.7c-0.9-0.9-1.8-2-2.2-3.3 c-0.7-2-0.2-4.2,1.5-7.1c0.2-0.4,0.5-0.9,0.8-1.3c1.1-1.6,2.1-3.4,2.5-5.3c0.1-0.7,0.3-1.5,0.4-2.5c0.7-4,1.5-9.6,3.5-11.9" data-code="Divider Warwicks West Mercia UKG" fill="white" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="divider"></path> 
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the transform and I've changed the colors but I hope the paths are what you need.

```css
svg{width:400px}
```

```html
<svg width="635" height="500" viewBox="465 970 200 150">
 
 <path id="a" stroke="green" d="M589.4,1078.4C584.1,1075.8000000000002,580.5,1071.6000000000001,577.3,1067.7C576.4,1066.8,575.5,1065.7,575.0999999999999,1064.4C574.3999999999999,1062.4,574.8999999999999,1060.2,576.5999999999999,1057.3000000000002C576.8,1056.9,577.0999999999999,1056.4,577.3999999999999,1056.0000000000002C578.4999999999999,1054.4000000000003,579.4999999999999,1052.6000000000001,579.8999999999999,1050.7000000000003C579.9999999999999,1050.0000000000002,580.1999999999998,1049.2000000000003,580.2999999999998,1048.2000000000003C580.9999999999999,1044.2000000000003,581.7999999999998,1038.6000000000004,583.7999999999998,1036.3000000000002
                  L580.9,1036.4C579.9,1036.4,578.8,1036.6000000000001,577.8,1036.4C576.5999999999999,1036.2,575.3,1036,574.1999999999999,1035.5C572.9,1034.9,571.3,1033.8,569.8,1033.7C569.0999999999999,1033.4,564.0999999999999,1033.3,562.9,1033.6000000000001C561.1,1033.7,558.9,1035.1000000000001,557.9,1036.5000000000002C557.9,1036.5000000000002,551.6,1030.7000000000003,551,1026.1000000000001C551,1025.6000000000001,550.9,1025.2,550.9,1024.7C550.8,1023.5,550.6999999999999,1022.2,550.1999999999999,1021C549.9,1020.3,549.4,1019.7,548.9999999999999,1019.1C548.3999999999999,1018.2,547.6999999999999,1017.3000000000001,547.4999999999999,1016.2C547.3999999999999,1015.7,547.3999999999999,1015.2,547.4999999999999,1014.7C547.5999999999999,1013.4000000000001,548.2999999999998,1012.1,548.9999999999999,1010.8000000000001C549.7999999999998,1009.4000000000001,550.4999999999999,1008.0000000000001,550.5999999999999,1006.6C550.5999999999999,1005.1,549.8999999999999,1003.6,549.3,1002.3000000000001C547.9,999.3000000000001,546.4,996.1,544,993.6C543.2,992.8000000000001,542.3,992,541.5,991.3000000000001C540.4,990.3000000000001,539.2,989.3000000000001,538.3,988.1C536.8,986.2,535.5999999999999,983.2,537.0999999999999,980.8000000000001C537.0999999999999,980.8000000000001,537.8999999999999,979.6,538.0999999999999,979.3000000000001C538.4999999999999,978.5000000000001,538.6999999999999,977.7,538.0999999999999,977.2C537.8999999999999,977.2,536.1999999999999,976.3000000000001,535.8,975.4000000000001L535.3,976.6000000000001L533.4,977.5000000000001L530.8,977.7000000000002L528.0999999999999,977.1000000000001L526.5999999999999,978.5000000000001L523.9999999999999,977.7000000000002L522.3999999999999,977.9000000000002L520.9999999999999,975.2000000000002L517.7999999999998,974.1000000000001L510.6999999999998,978.1000000000001L510.79999999999984,978.9000000000001L510.59999999999985,981.6000000000001L504.79999999999984,984.2000000000002L503.29999999999984,983.7000000000002L498.39999999999986,979.7000000000002L496.39999999999986,979.4000000000002L492.1999999999999,980.3000000000002L488.89999999999986,978.1000000000001L485.29999999999984,977.8000000000002L477.39999999999986,981.4000000000002L476.79999999999984,984.2000000000002L475.49999999999983,985.7000000000002L475.99999999999983,989.1000000000001L472.6999999999998,992.0000000000001L472.99999999999983,995.7000000000002L476.8999999999998,996.8000000000002L479.1999999999998,997.0000000000002L481.6999999999998,998.9000000000002L485.8999999999998,999.8000000000002L489.2999999999998,1002.8000000000002L487.69999999999976,1005.5000000000002L484.19999999999976,1006.8000000000002L483.19999999999976,1008.7000000000002L482.69999999999976,1013.4000000000002L480.2999999999998,1015.0000000000002L479.0999999999998,1018.9000000000002L475.3999999999998,1021.5000000000002L475.49999999999983,1022.4000000000002L477.1999999999998,1026.9L478.99999999999983,1026.7L480.29999999999984,1025.1000000000001L485.39999999999986,1022.1000000000001L486.59999999999985,1022.3000000000002L487.99999999999983,1024.3000000000002L488.3999999999998,1026.3000000000002L484.2999999999998,1031.0000000000002L476.69999999999976,1031.7000000000003L470.09999999999974,1034.5000000000002L467.09999999999974,1036.7000000000003L467.39999999999975,1038.8000000000002L469.69999999999976,1040.2000000000003L477.09999999999974,1045.7000000000003L480.69999999999976,1047.8000000000002L490.2999999999998,1048.7000000000003L490.19999999999976,1050.7000000000003L487.59999999999974,1052.7000000000003L486.7999999999997,1054.1000000000004L487.09999999999974,1055.3000000000004L489.89999999999975,1056.6000000000004L490.2999999999997,1058.1000000000004L489.4999999999997,1058.8000000000004L486.09999999999974,1059.6000000000004L482.09999999999974,1061.8000000000004L480.39999999999975,1064.3000000000004L477.7999999999997,1068.9000000000003L477.4999999999997,1069.9000000000003L478.59999999999974,1070.4000000000003L479.69999999999976,1071.0000000000002L478.59999999999974,1073.0000000000002L476.2999999999997,1074.2000000000003L476.09999999999974,1074.9000000000003L477.39999999999975,1076.3000000000004L476.2999999999997,1077.6000000000004L476.09999999999974,1080.7000000000003L478.89999999999975,1082.9000000000003L479.89999999999975,1086.4000000000003L484.2999999999997,1092.5000000000002L486.9999999999997,1094.6000000000001L488.2999999999997,1097.2L490.09999999999974,1098.5L491.4999999999997,1098.8L495.4999999999997,1096.8L497.6999999999997,1096.5L506.0999999999997,1102.8L509.29999999999967,1106.6L512.3999999999996,1106.8999999999999L515.9999999999997,1109.1999999999998L516.6999999999997,1108.8999999999999L517.1999999999997,1106.1999999999998L518.0999999999997,1105.1L518.9999999999997,1105.3L519.5999999999997,1106.7L521.0999999999997,1105.9L522.1999999999997,1106L522.8999999999997,1104.9L525.2999999999997,1104.1000000000001L527.8999999999997,1104.4L529.2999999999997,1102L532.2999999999997,1101.7L535.1999999999997,1100.2L534.1999999999997,1099L532.8999999999997,1095.6L531.5999999999998,1094.3999999999999L530.9999999999998,1093.3L531.1999999999998,1091.3L532.0999999999998,1089.8999999999999L531.7999999999998,1088.6L533.2999999999998,1085.8L534.9999999999999,1086.5L536.1999999999999,1088.7L537.3,1089.2L538.8,1088.7L541.0999999999999,1086.6000000000001L543.4999999999999,1086.3000000000002L546.7999999999998,1091.1000000000001L551.3999999999999,1092.3000000000002L552.6999999999998,1092.2000000000003L554.8999999999999,1089.3000000000002L557.2999999999998,1090.3000000000002L558.1999999999998,1089.5000000000002L557.7999999999998,1087.6000000000001L557.8999999999999,1083.8000000000002L558.8999999999999,1083.5000000000002L563.0999999999999,1083.2000000000003L560.8999999999999,1087.9000000000003L562.5999999999999,1088.9000000000003L564.0999999999999,1087.3000000000004H567.1999999999999L570.5999999999999,1088.2000000000005L575.5999999999999,1085.3000000000004L578.1999999999999,1084.8000000000004L583.4999999999999,1085.4000000000003L586.9999999999999,1087.7000000000003L587.6999999999999,1086.0000000000002L585.9,1083.8000000000002L584.3,1082.9L584.4,1081.4L586.3,1079.9L588.9,1080.3000000000002" fill="gold"/>
  
  
  <path  d="
                         M588.9,1080.3000000000002L591.6,1076.8000000000002L593.5,1075.9L595.7,1077.8000000000002L597.7,1078.5000000000002L598.5,1080.7000000000003L601.2,1084.5000000000002L602.5,1084.9000000000003L605.5,1084.5000000000002L606.5,1085.0000000000002L607.1,1085.9000000000003L602.9,1090.0000000000002L607.5,1093.2000000000003L608.4,1091.9000000000003L611.1999999999999,1091.7000000000003L611.8,1089.9000000000003L613.9,1089.5000000000002L615.6,1083.8000000000002V1081.5000000000002L618.1,1077.9000000000003L620.6,1077.6000000000004V1076.1000000000004L622,1075.5000000000005L623.9,1075.7000000000005L626.1999999999999,1077.4000000000005L627.6999999999999,1077.1000000000006L628.0999999999999,1076.5000000000007L626.4999999999999,1075.1000000000006V1074.5000000000007L629.0999999999999,1072.7000000000007L629.6999999999999,1070.6000000000008L632.4,1067.2000000000007L637.1,1065.5000000000007L637.3000000000001,1064.7000000000007L635.6,1062.9000000000008L635.8000000000001,1061.7000000000007L640.6,1059.2000000000007L640.5,1057.0000000000007L639.3,1055.4000000000008L641,1053.5000000000007L638.1,1052.8000000000006L637.3000000000001,1051.1000000000006L643.3000000000001,1048.9000000000005L644.5000000000001,1048.1000000000006L640.6000000000001,1040.7000000000005L638.0000000000001,1039.4000000000005L633.5000000000001,1033.3000000000006L624.7000000000002,1029.5000000000007L622.8000000000002,1026.8000000000006L616.1000000000001,1024.4000000000005L614.0000000000001,1022.3000000000005L611.7000000000002,1021.6000000000005V1019.0000000000005V1018.9000000000004C610.7000000000002,1020.2000000000004,610.0000000000001,1023.6000000000005,610.7000000000002,1025.0000000000005C611.3000000000002,1025.9000000000005,612.0000000000001,1026.7000000000005,612.8000000000002,1027.5000000000005C613.2000000000002,1027.9000000000005,613.6000000000001,1028.4000000000005,614.0000000000002,1028.8000000000004C615.9000000000002,1031.0000000000005,616.9000000000002,1033.8000000000004,617.0000000000002,1037.0000000000005C617.0000000000002,1037.5000000000005,617.0000000000002,1038.1000000000004,616.6000000000003,1038.5000000000005C616.3000000000003,1038.8000000000004,616.0000000000002,1038.7000000000005,615.7000000000003,1038.9000000000005C613.5000000000002,1040.1000000000006,610.9000000000003,1041.3000000000006,608.2000000000003,1041.3000000000006C608.1000000000003,1041.3000000000006,607.9000000000003,1041.3000000000006,607.8000000000003,1041.3000000000006C606.7000000000003,1041.3000000000006,605.5000000000003,1040.8000000000006,604.5000000000003,1040.6000000000006C601.7000000000004,1040.1000000000006,599.0000000000003,1039.4000000000005,596.3000000000003,1038.7000000000005C592.5000000000003,1037.7000000000005,588.6000000000003,1036.6000000000006,584.6000000000003,1036.200000000000
                         
                         L583.7999999999998,1036.3000000000002C581.7999999999998,1038.6000000000004 580.9999999999999,1044.2000000000003 580.2999999999998,1048.2000000000003C580.1999999999998,1049.2000000000003 579.9999999999999,1050.0000000000002 579.8999999999999,1050.7000000000003C579.4999999999999,1052.6000000000001 578.4999999999999,1054.4000000000003 577.3999999999999,1056.0000000000002C577.0999999999999,1056.4 576.8,1056.9 576.5999999999999,1057.3000000000002C574.8999999999999,1060.2 574.3999999999999,1062.4 575.0999999999999,1064.4C575.5,1065.7 576.4,1066.8 577.3,1067.7C580.5,1071.6000000000001 584.1,1075.8000000000002 589.4,1078.4z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.1)" stroke="blue" class="region" cursor="pointer"></path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain how you generated this?

Comment: First I've changed your path's commands to uppercase. You can do it using this tool:[Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv). Next I can break your path in two parts and add the divider as it is to the first part and the reversed divider to the second. In order to know where to break your path I had to read the code and look for values near the values for the start and the end of the divider